# VBA userform make radio button remember last choice

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make my application to remember last choice from userform radio button, without saving changes and even when the file will be closed.
I know that i have to change value of the control but how to keep it saved when the file will be closed.
Regards
Michał

Comment: Do you have any code or can you explain why you're trying to save the state of your VBA form?

Comment: Right now , the only way I can think of is to write the state of the button to a cell in a worksheet. You can use a hidden worksheet if you don't want to see it. But you should save the changes to the workbook...

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler I know that code is always welcome, but don't think this time is so necesary. IMHO, OP is not even asking for a code, but just an idea to get started.

Comment: I may be wrong, but in computers, "remember" always means "saving something somewhere". I believe you should rethink what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @CMArg Thank you very much. I'll follow that idea.

Comment: @Eswemenasja you can save to registry

Answer (score 0):

You can use SaveSetting to save the setting to the registry, they sit then in the VB and VBA program settings.

Answer (score 0):

Saving to the registry might be a bit extreme (and dangerous if you don't know what you are doing). A simpler method a lot of people use is to write the data to a cell on a hidden worksheet when you change the button value, then when you are loading the application/userform or whatever read back the value from that cell and modify the button accordingly.